# CanJS: how to package view templates for production

Tags: canjs, canjs-view

What is the optimal way of packaging view templates for production use?

I have a number of .stache files. In development they are loaded synchronously with can.view(). In production i want to avoid multiple HTTP requests.

What is the right way to do it? Should i bundle them as single html file or single js file? Which format does StealJS use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I created [can-compile](https://github.com/daffl/can-compile) for. For example

> can-compile **/*.stache --out views.combined.js --can 2.1.0

Compiles all Stache files in the current folder and all subfolders into `views.combined.js`.

If you use Steal and the [latest steal-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steal-tools) (which is currently pending a release) and you import your modules e.g. using ES6 with

```
import template from 'my/template.stache!';
```

The view will be built into the production bundle automatically (and also loaded asynchronously in development).